# Amazon CloudFront - Restrict MP3 to play on specific website

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, mediaelement.js

I've been trying figure out how to get mp3 files in an Amazon S3 bucket paired with Cloudfront to allow me to stream the files directly on my site but not allow anyone to take the source URL of the mp3s by viewing the source code of the page and then sharing or leeching the link.

Right now, I am using an html5 mp3 playlist from mediaelements.js and the mp3 file is always in the source code. That's fine, but I want to only allow the mp3 to play on my specific website and if the link gets copied from the source and accessed in a different browser it should show an access restricted error.

I tired to update the cloudfront policy to expire within 30 seconds of the page load, but that will ultimately prevent the files from playing once the 30 seconds is over and if the user didn't play one of the tracks prior to that expiration.

Is there another way to do this without putting a time expiration on the cloudfront links?

Comment: Don't HTTP `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls-overview.html

Basically you can vend URLs dynamically from your service, and CloudFront will validate signature. You can also set pretty short expiration time to avoid wide distribution of your URL, and restrict IP addresses that might access URL (see Custom Policies section in the referenced document).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. MediaElements.js may be hosted on your site, but it's being run on the user's computer. So although it looks like they are playing an MP3 via your site, they are actually just downloading a URL from your site and playing it using code running on their computer.

You could write server-side code that went off to S3 and retrieved the MP3 before returning it as if it were a file hosted on your server, but that still wouldn't limit people from copying that link, unless some sort of session were used before returning the file to ensure they're logged in via your site.

But that would mean you can't make use of CloudFront. That's the compromise. Distribute your MP3 via a CDN and improve download performance by hosting the file in an edge location closer to your users, or take advantage of server-side security to ensure your IP isn't hosted by unscrupulous third parties.

Comment: That makes sense. I wonder if it's possible to specifically load the mp3 files in the user's browser cache so that they load before the cloudfront link expires?

Answer (score 0):

*It's possible with just few line wizard coding on back-end (private method) ,i prefer to using free tier EC2 instance and configure environment for handle streamable contents for deliver everything clear this way provide a restrict page to someone going to leech or using IDM for donwload your mp3 files.*

```
Example : Grooveshark.com
```

However still there is some another methods like Owain answer .